# Значение атрибута data-title

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как должен выглядеть атрибут data-title, чтобы указывался не заголовок страницы, а название статьи?

Comment: атрибут "data" не имеет стандартного значения, в нем будет находится то, что в него покладут: заголовок, значит заголовок; название статьи и, значит название статьи. Без кода, на Ваш вопрос ответить нельзя.

Comment: Ну так мне и надо узнать, что нужно в него положить, чтобы отображался заголовок статьи. Сейчас у меня отображается заголовок страницы

Comment: положите заголовок статьи

Comment: так мне не нужен заголовок страницы! он отличается от заголовка статьи. я не знаю как положить, потому и спрашиваю

Comment: Спокойствие и только спокойствие: я сам заметил ошибку и исправился

Comment: data-title="?" что должно быть вместо вопроса, чтобы на любой странице отображался заголовок статьи?

Comment: Ну, очевидно же: там должен быть заголовок статьи

Comment: Просто дайте мне пример кода) вы меня не понимаете. я же не могу его вручную прописывать, он должен сам отображаться, но как задать этот параметр?

Comment: Можно и вручную прописать. Все от ситуации зависит. Универсального кода нет

Comment: Сейчас он выглядит вот так: <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram"></div> Но при репосте отображается название страницы, а мне надо, чтобы название статьи отображалось

Comment: Вы предлагаете ванговать? Какую CMS используете?

Comment: laravel вроде бы)

Comment: В laravel каждый сам себе хозяин) Как выход. Расположите код шаринга после вывода заголовка или статьи и пропишите в `data-title` код, который выводится внутри тега заголовка статьи. Что там за код - знаете только вы.

Comment: <div class="wrap-contaier news_block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="page_block row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="page_container">
                          <div class="f_post_text">

                              <span>Сиамская кошка</span>
Что именно вписать в data-title?

Answer (score 1):

Мда....
Тогда вам подойдёт вот такое решение.
Формируем вставку шаринга через jQuery

```
    (function($){
    var newstitle = $('.f_post_text').text(),
        share = $('<div></div>', {
            class: "ya-share2"
        }).attr({
            'data-services': "vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram",
            'data-title': encodeURIComponent(newstitle)
        }),
        script = $('<script></script>', {
            src: "ваш_share_скрипт.js"
        });
    $("body").append(share, script);
    $(document).on('click', '#share42 a', function(e){
        /**
         * Обрабатываем клик
         */
    });
}(jQuery));
```